'Galois cohomology of elliptic curves' , Poitou-Tate sequence
This is a question about exact sequence of p5 of 'Galois cohomology of elliptic curves' by Coates Sujatha which is called Pitou-Tate exact sequence.
Let $F$ be a number field. Let $S$ be a finite set of non-archimedean primes of $F$.
Let $G_S$ be maximal unramified extension outside $S$.For $v\in S$, denote $F_v$ be completion of $F$ at $v$. Let $M$ be a finite $G_S$module. Let $M^D$ be Tate-twist of $M$.
Let $β_M$ be the following map.
$β_M :H^1(G_S,M) \to \bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(F_v,M^D) $
$\widehat{β_M} : \bigoplus_{v\in S}H^1(F_v,M^D)\to \widehat{H^1(G_S,M)}$
where $\widehat{β_M}$ denotes a dual of $β_M$.
p5 of 'Galois cohomology of elliptic curves' by Coates Sujatha states

$\text{image}(β_M)=\text{ker}(\widehat{β_{M^D}})$

Why does this hold ? In general,$\text{image}(β_M)$ should be annihilator of
$\text{ker}(\widehat{β_{M^D}})$, not equal.
P.S What in my mind is $M : E[2]$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve. So in this case $M^D=M$.

[

I don't think this makes sense either. Maybe they meant to write annihilator? I can't think of what else it could mean.

@Snacc They present this as an exact sequence, and the argument proceeds as follows. I can't believe such a mistake exists, given the context of the entire text

can you link an image of the text? I don't have a copy and would like to see it.

@Snacc I added a picture.

Looking at the pictures, they are asserting that $\text{ker}(\widehat{\beta_{M^D}})=\text{im}(\beta_M)$, where we note that they are not claiming $\text{ker}(\widehat{\beta_M})=\text{im}(\beta_M)$ like you suggested in the body of your post. Indeed, the second equality is impossible: the two sets are not even contained in the same place!

@Snacc Thank you very much, It was my typo. If you ask whether it still equals in that case, I think it's questionable, so could you please explain why it would hold in that case?

@Snacc The $M$ in my mind were all related to elliptic curves, so $M^D=M$. Sorry for confusion.

The fact that $\text{ker}(\widehat{\beta_{M^D}})=\text{im}(\beta_M)$ is, as far as I'm aware, extremely deep. The proof of this exact sequence is contained in section 8.6 of Cohomology of Number Fields and is over 10 pages long. I don't know enough to speak about it in any detail.

Thank you very much. By the way, in section 8.6 of Cohomology of Number Fields, the author always deals with $G_S$, not $G_K$ (the absolute Galois group of $K$) when $S$ is the set of all places of $K$. Is it correct to understand that all arguments apply to the case of $G_K$? I'm asking this question because in Galois Cohomology of Elliptic Curves, they consistently handle the case where $S$ is finite, and we cannot take $G_K$ as $G_S$, although I don't understand why we should assume $S$ is finite.
